# Alternative to keyframes in CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to create a loading spinner, at the moment I am using the following code.

I would like to know if is possible to rewrite it using an alternative syntax for `keyframes` (maybe transitions?).

Unfortunately I am using a build tool which rewrite `keyframes` properties adding bugs and the [CSS generated is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35411580/dojo-with-xstyle-issue-with-css-keyframes) so I would like to work around the problem.

A JS solution is also possible, adding CSS inline.

```css
.loadingSpinner {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 5px solid #3498db;
    border-top-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border-left-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-animation: loadingSpinner 0.7s infinite linear;
    -o-animation: loadingSpinner 0.7s infinite linear;
    -webkit-animation: loadingSpinner 0.7s infinite linear;
    animation: loadingSpinner 0.7s infinite linear;
}

@-moz-keyframes loadingSpinner {
  0%   {
      -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);

  }
  100% {
      -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@-o-keyframes loadingSpinner {
  0%   {
      -o-transform: rotate(0deg);

  }
  100% {
      -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes loadingSpinner {
  0%   {
      -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);

  }
  100% {
      -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes loadingSpinner {
  0%   {
      transform: rotate(0deg);

  }
  100% {
      transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="loadingSpinner"></div>
```

Comment: related for option with css inline: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14409706/using-an-inline-animation-keyframes-definition

Answer (score 3):

You could use a very long transition and trigger it with a quick js line.
For example, add a .start class that triggers a 60 second transition that rotates the spinner several times (for example, 36000deg).

```
.loadingSpinner {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 5px solid #3498db;
    border-top-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border-left-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border-radius: 50%;
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    transition: transform 60s;
}

.loadingSpinner.start {
    transform: rotate(36000deg);
}
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/6tkf1f95/1/

Comment: Thanks, interesting idea. Do you know a different way to make it looks like rotating for unlimited amount of time instead of using rotate(36000deg)?

Comment: Rotate 360deg with a javascript Interval

Answer (score 0):

what about only css solution?

```css
@keyframes spinner {
    to {transform: rotate(360deg);}
}
 
@-webkit-keyframes spinner {
    to {-webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);}
}
 
.spinner {
    min-width: 30px;
    min-height: 30px;
}
 
.spinner:before {
    content: 'Loading…';
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    margin-top: -13px;
    margin-left: -13px;
}
 
.spinner:not(:required):before {
    content: '';
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 5px solid #ccc;
    border-top-color: #03ade0;
    animation: spinner .7s linear infinite;
    -webkit-animation: spinner .7s linear infinite;
}
```

```html
<div class="spinner"></div>
```

Comment: thanks for posting but actually I needed to have a version which does not use @keyframes... could you please revise it?

Comment: sure, give me few minutes =)s

Comment: I have bad news = ( I have tried out Several things and find out that you have to use Js or keyframe for the spinner rotate. Without keyframe or js  browser doesnt know when he  should start the animation. I think that @ezakto solution ist the best one in your fall

Answer (score 0):

You can create an *infinite* **CSS** `transition` using a single **CSS Custom Property**, the value of which you can update every time the JavaScript `transitionend` event fires.

In the CSS stylesheet, we can start with the following `transform` and `transition`:

```
  transform: var(--rotation);
  transition: transform 0.7s linear;
```

We will need to initialise `--rotation`, so we can do that at the top of the stylesheet:

```
:root {
  --rotation: rotate(0deg);
}
```

So far, so good. Now we need a JS function which moves the rotation value up by `360deg` every time the transition completes:

```
const rotateSpinner = () => {

  let loadingSpinnerStyles = window.getComputedStyle(loadingSpinner);
  let rotation = loadingSpinnerStyles.getPropertyValue('--rotation');
  rotation = parseInt(rotation.replace('rotate(', '').replace('deg)', '')) + 360;
  rotation = 'rotate(' + rotation + 'deg)';
  loadingSpinner.style.setProperty('--rotation', rotation);
}
```

When we put everything together, we get the working example below.

---

**Working Example:**

```js
const loadingSpinner = document.querySelector('.loadingSpinner');

const rotateSpinner = () => {

  let loadingSpinnerStyles = window.getComputedStyle(loadingSpinner);
  let rotation = loadingSpinnerStyles.getPropertyValue('--rotation');
  rotation = parseInt(rotation.replace('rotate(', '').replace('deg)', '')) + 360;
  rotation = 'rotate(' + rotation + 'deg)';
  loadingSpinner.style.setProperty('--rotation', rotation);
}

loadingSpinner.addEventListener('transitionend', rotateSpinner);
window.addEventListener('load', rotateSpinner);
```

```css
:root {
  --rotation: rotate(0deg);
}

.loadingSpinner {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 5px solid #3498db;
  border-top-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  border-left-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: var(--rotation);
  transition: transform 0.7s linear;
}
```

```html
<div class="loadingSpinner"></div>
```